# How to get first username in database with linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want get first username that register in my site.
I have following code:

```
Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
string username = db.tblMembers.Min().Select(x => x.username);
```

But not working.

I try this:

```
string username = db.tblMembers.Min(x=>x.CreateTime).Select(x => x.username);
```

but not work.

Comment: do you have `CreatedTime` field in your `tblMembers` table ? Can you show me your Database table structure ?

Comment: yes i have CreatedTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
var YourFirstUser = db.tblMembers.OrderBy( u => u.CreatedTime).Select( u => u.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create `CreatedTime` or `InsertedTime` in your Database table if you don't have it ! And you can order by this time field , and get the top value ,

```
Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
string username =  
db.tblMembers.OrderBy(n => n.CreatedTime.Value).Select(x => x.username).Take(1);
```

Comment: not work: Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'CreatedTime' and no extension method 'CreatedTime' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)66 mvc2

Comment: This isn't going to work. Once you issue a Select(x => x.username), you're no longer working with the Member Class; You're working with an iEnumerable<string>